# FTPS error: Winsock error 10060

Tags: ssl, ftp, openssl, ftps

I have setup an FTPS server on ubuntu using vsftps

Here are the FTP configurations: `sudo vim /etc/vsftpd.conf`

```
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=NO
# pasv_address=13.55.13.221 
idle_session_timeout=1200
data_connection_timeout=3600
accept_timeout=500
connect_timeout=5000
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/home/$USER/uploads
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=50000
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
userlist_deny=NO
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
utf8_filesystem=YES
```

I test the server using Core FTP LE, I have three options:

1. AUTH SSL <-- Works Fine
   [image]

---

2. Auth TLS <-- Works Fine
   [image]

---

3. FTPS (SSL Direct) <-- Does not work
   [image]

---

This is the error that I am getting:

> SSL/TLS error - 0, SSL error - 1,
> error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1)    Winsock error 10060 (A
> connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
> respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
> because connected host has failed to respond.  )   SSL Connection not
> established

Any idea how to get the FTPS option working?

Comment: FTPS - FTP with implicit SSL/TLS - uses ports 990/989 by default instead of 21/20. Have you opened those ports on the local firewall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Core FTP LE uses Implicit FTPS authentication and my server was configured to use Explicit Authentication.

Implicit Authentication is [deprecated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS#Implicit), however if you want to use it, you need to add the following in your `/etc/vsftpd.conf`:

```
implicit_ssl=YES
listen_port=990 # or use 21 if you prefer
```